# Which UUID/GUID generator to use with JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, guid, uuid

I want to generate unique Ids as a key for multiple physically separated databases.

I use JBoss and I wonder which implemetation/library is the way to go. I know `java.util.UUID` would be simple and probably fine. I'd just like to know if this is the way to go in JBoss.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is an [UUID generator in JBoss](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/KeyGenerator) that can be called using this code:

```
   InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
   KeyGeneratorFactory kgf = (KeyGeneratorFactory) ctx.lookup("UUIDKeyGeneratorFactory");
   KeyGenerator kg = kgf.getKeyGenerator();
   Object uuid = kg.generateKey();
```

Comment: Yes found that one too. But is this the recommended way to go in JBOSS ?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by recommended?

UUID is a standard. There are different kinds of UUID (which are also defined as standards). It doesn't matter which library or implementation you use, as long as the generated keys follow the standard (in other, as long as it works).

I would think that the JDK implementation of UUID is pretty reliable. It's part of the Java API, it's simple, I don't see a reason not to use it. In fact, that's what I'm using in a EJB 3.0 application (which runs on JBoss).

The UUID generator provided by JBoss AS was added in version 3.2 (according to the link in another answer). This generator was included probably because when JBoss 3.2 was released, the JDK didn't supply the `java.util.UUID` class, which was introduced in Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Andre Rodrigues is correct.

You should study up on the versions (types) of UUID. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) does a good job of explaining.

The [java.util.UUID class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) generates only versions 3 (name-based, via method `nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[] name)`) and 4 (entirely random, via method `randomUUID()`) UUIDs. Sun/Oracle claim they provide a "cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator". That means you should not have any real chance of collisions even if creating billions or trillions of values.

For security reasons, Java does not generate the original version which uses your network interface's MAC address plus the current date-time. In theory, this version is even less likely to have collisions than version 4. Indeed collisions are virtually impossible. If that is the kind of UUID you want, you can create one by calling another library. Most operating systems nowadays come bundled with a UUID generator, such as [uuidgen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/uuidgen.1.html) in [BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) and OS X. Then pass the bits or hex-string to one of the constructors or factory methods found on java.util.UUID.